# Ubuntu-Specific problem with Wine 5

Tags: wine, 20.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm now finding that a Windows 32bit application will not run correctly under Wine.

The problem seems to be Ubuntu 20.04-specific, as the program will run fine if I go back to my original partition and run it from Ubuntu 18.04 (which runs Wine 3.0 while Ubuntu 20.04 runs Wine 5.0). In both cases, the same application is being run with the same environment, as 18.04 and 20.04 are installed on different partitions, but both using the same /home partition.

If I install the WineHQ version of Wine 5.0 under Ubuntu 20.04, the application runs fine, again using the same original environment.

My questions are:

- how and where do I report the problem? Who builds the version of Wine that ships with Ubuntu?
- how do I figure out if the problem lies in Wine, Ubuntu, or in just a missing dependency in the Ubuntu-Wine package?